# astropy FITS with multiple headers

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I'm trying to create a FITS file in Python but I appear to be having problems when compiling the headers and PrimaryHDU together.

I've made a simple example which will give the error that I'm getting:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

a = np.ones([5,5])
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(a)
hdr = fits.Header()
hdr['NPIX1'] = 60
hdr['NPIX2'] = 60
hdr['CRPIX1'] = 0
hdr['CRPIX2'] = 0
primary_hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(header=hdr)
hdul = fits.HDUList([primary_hdu, hdu])
hdul.writeto('table4.fits')
```

When running this code, I get the following error:

> VerifyError: 
>       Verification reported errors:
>       HDUList's element 1 is not an extension HDU.
>       Note: astropy.io.fits uses zero-based indexing.

I've seen some posts which claim this could be to do with the PrimaryHDU needing to be the first in the HDUList when exporting but looking at my code, I believe I'm doing that already.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the error message:

> VerifyError: Verification reported errors: HDUList's element 1 is not an extension HDU. Note: astropy.io.fits uses zero-based indexing.

The second item in the `HDUList` is *also* a `PrimaryHDU`, which is not a valid extension HDU (`Primary` here essentially means first and unique).

Make that HDU an `ImageHDU`, and things will work:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

a = np.ones([5,5])
hdu = fits.ImageHDU(a)     # Don't use a `PrimaryHDU` here
hdr = fits.Header()
hdr['NPIX1'] = 60
hdr['NPIX2'] = 60
hdr['CRPIX1'] = 0
hdr['CRPIX2'] = 0
primary_hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(header=hdr)
hdul = fits.HDUList([primary_hdu, hdu])
hdul.writeto('table4.fits')
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! Strange how you can't forcefully change the PrimaryHDU header to become what you want to but this way I still have the information so thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if there were some way to simply automatically convert a `PrimaryHDU` to a plain `ImageHDU` extension, since there's not otherwise much difference under the hood.  I'm not really sure what the right balance is though because the current behavior also catches programming errors, as it did in your case.  So it's probably better safer than sorry.